# session.* files in .emacs.d

Tags: session, emacs

I see files starting with session.* like the below in my ".emacs.d"

```
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.101a02e0b94eb58b84148237161522128000000018520056
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.10381df9de9bb3d3d6148230720853261500000024450062
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.1045c7fe8152d73e13148318808128329600000024110055
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.1090e78f769193bf5c148236902921101500000018660054
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.10910a975357e26c18148321136168657600000134250054
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.10b644daa3f8e4c17c148229635967581900000021520055
-rw-r--r--   1 cysh           cysh            0 2017-01-05 21:44 session.10da28c33c6cc823b2148239157050392100000019660055
```

I'd like to know where those come from and how to move its location to where I want.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12773/8430. I am not sure how to change the location for these files.